# IE JavaScript Mystery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript function

```
function headerBanner(){
    var current = $('.bannerImages img:nth-child('+bannerIndex+')').css('display', 'none');
    if(bannerIndex== $('.bannerImages img').size()){
        bannerIndex= 1;
    }else{
        bannerIndex= (bannerIndex*1)+1;
    }
    var next =  $('.bannerImages img:nth-child('+bannerIndex+')').css('display', 'block');
}
```

In every browser on the planet, with the exception of IE (8, 7 or less), the above code is working correctly. In Internet Explorer it's going through it and having no effect. I've put alerts at every line of the function and they all fire, even in IE, but the banner simply doesn't change. Is there any reason as to why this is so?

The HTML attached for this function is the following:

```
<div class='bannerImages'>
    <img src="FirstImage.jpg" />
    <img src="SecondImage.jpg" />
    <img src="ThirdImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some reason that you're not simply using hide()/show()?

Comment: try difining the bannerIndex like var bannerIndex; at the beginning of the function!

Comment: @tvanfosson Hide()/show() is not having any effect anyway in ie.

@aSeptik bannerIndex is defined elsewhere and it's working just fine in any other browser.

Comment: maybe your problem is not on this function! cause you are saying that you don't give any alert from the function, this mean that process is stopping before executing it! peraph, try to put just **alert(bannerIndex);** in it and see what's happen!

Comment: @aSeptik I'm getting alerts from the function, at every line, somehow the Hide/Show or setting the Display is having no effect at all.

Comment: @Yisroel I've uploaded the HTML sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ipudo/4

```
$(function(){
    $('.bannerImages img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.bannerImages :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.bannerImages');}, 
      3000);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the script debugger in the IE8 developer tools and put some breakpoints in to check the value of bannerIndex.  If it's possible that it's not a number you may want to use parseInt() to convert it to a number and IsNaN() to ensure that it is, rather than relying on arithmetic operations to normalize it for you.

Comment: I've checked the numbers and they are all figure however for some reason in IE jQuery $('.bannerImages img').css('display') isn't returning anything while in otherbrowser it is

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found with `hide()` and `show()` was that, sometimes, if you set the display to none, show() will not work. So, I always create the element then call a hide(0) on it first thing when document is ready.

Also, did you check the length of `$('.bannerImages img:nth-child('+bannerIndex+')')` to make sure it's not 0?

Last thing, `$('.bannerImages img').size()` isn't 1, right? It would make sense if `$('.bannerImages img').size()` is 1 and `bannerIndex` is 1, then it will not change anything when it go through your `headerBanner();`

ps: I'm sure you won't make some simple mistake such as bannerIndex was started from 0 instead of 1...

Oh, btw, there is a firebug for IE, which u need to include a script in your header